# Spring return JSON for HTTP 406 (NOT_ACCEPTABLE)

Tags: java, spring, rest, http, exception

Spring allows the definition of `@ExceptionHandlers` inside of `@RestControllerAdvice`.

I already defined a lot of other `ExceptionHandlers` in there for HTTP 400, 404, 405,... However the ExceptionHandler for HTTP 406 (NOT_ACCEPTABLE) does not seem to work. The handler is triggered, I checked that in the logs, but the result is not used.

My goal is it to return a HTTP 406 with a JSON body.

**Variant 1**

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
@ExceptionHandler(HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException.class)
public ErrorDTO requestMethodNotSupported(final HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException e) {
    final ErrorDTO dto = new ErrorDTO(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE, "http.media_not_acceptable");
    return dto;
}
```

**Variant 2**

```
@ExceptionHandler(HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ErrorDTO> requestMethodNotSupported2(final HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException e) {
    final ErrorDTO dto = new ErrorDTO(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE, "http.media_not_acceptable");
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8).body(dto);
}
```

But I always get a HTML response similar to this from the Tomcat:

> HTTP Status 406 -
>
> type: Status report
>
> message:
>
> description:  The resource identified by
>   this request is only capable of generating responses with
>   characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept"
>   headers.

instead of

> {
>   "errorCode": 406,
>   "errorMessage": "http.media_not_acceptable"
>   }

**Request-Headers:**

- Accept: application/stuff-that-cannot-be-present

**Actual-Response-Headers:**

- Content-Type: text/html

**Expected-Response-Headers:**

- Content-Type: application/json

I know that I could simply "fix" the Accept-Header that is send by the client, however the server should always respond in JSON, if it does not know how to respond.

I use Spring 4.3.3.RELEASE and Jackson 2.8.4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I found a solution for this:

Instead of returning a serializable object just return the bytes directly.

```
private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

@ExceptionHandler(HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException.class)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> mediaTypeNotAcceptable(HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException e) {
    Object response = ...;
    try {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .body(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(response));
    } catch (Exception subException) {
        // Should never happen!!!
        subException.addSuppressed(e);
        throw subException;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

As an alternative you can create a custom `HttpMessageConverter<ErrorResponse>` for your `ErrorResponse` object.

- Go to your or create a impl of `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter#extendMessageConverters(converters)`
- Pick a `HttpMessageConverter` that is capable of creating your expected result/content type.
- Wrap it in a way to fulfill the following conditions:

  - `getSupportedMediaTypes()` returns `MediaType.ALL`
  - `canRead()` returns false
  - `canWrite()`returns only true for your `ErrorResponse`
  - `write()` sets the forced CT and forward your expected content type to the wrapped converter.
- Add your wrapper to the converters list.

  - If added as first element then it will always return your expected result (forced)

    - Requested: json , Returned: forced CT
    - Requested: xml , Returned: forced CT
    - Requested: image , Returned: forced CT
  - If added as last element then it will only return the result as your expected result, if there was no other matching converter (fallback)

    - Requested: json , Returned: json
    - Requested: xml , Returned: xml
    - Requested: image , Returned: forced CT

Answer (score 2):

Building on @ST-DDT findings. If you are also extending `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` then you cannot just add another method to handle `HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException`. However, there is an even simpler solution to the whole problem then:

```java
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMediaTypeNotAcceptable(HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        ResponseEntity<Object> response = super.handleHttpMediaTypeNotAcceptable(ex, headers, status, request);

        // Workaround to return JSON response for 406
        return ResponseEntity.status(NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
                .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(response.getBody());
    }
```