# Spring @ExceptionHandler returns HTTP 406

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, exception

I've got some strange Error.

What I want to do:
The client asks GET: /invoices/invoiceNumber with header Accept: application/pdf and I want to return PDF file. If client forgot about header I return HTTP 406.

The method that returns PDF bytes throws DocumentNotFoundException that is handled by Spring ExceptionHandler and should return 404, but it didn't. Instead of that, I've got 406 and server log:

```
 2017-06-01 15:14:03.844  WARN 2272 --- [qtp245298614-13] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler    : Error page loop /error
```

The same magic happens when Spring Security returns HTTP 401.

So I think that problem is that Client Accept `application/pdf` but Spring ExceptionHandler returns `application/json`, so jetty dispatcher override 404 with 406 :(

My code:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason = "Invoice not found")
@ExceptionHandler(DocumentNotFoundException.class)
public void handleException() {
    //impl not needed
}

@GetMapping(value = "invoices/**", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getInvoicePdf(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String invoiceNumber = extractInvoiceNumber(request);
    final byte[] invoicePdf = invoiceService.getInvoicePdf(invoiceNumber);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(invoicePdf, buildPdfFileHeader(invoiceNumber), HttpStatus.OK);

}

@GetMapping(value = "invoices/**")
public ResponseEntity getInvoiceOther() {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
}
```

Can someone help me with understanding that?

Comment: Make your client accept `application/json`

Comment: I want to return pdf or json metadata according to client Accept header, so I can't change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Spring tries to convert the error response to `application/pdf` but fails to find a suitable `HttpMessageConverter` which supports conversion to PDF.

The easiest solution is to manually create the error response:

```
@ExceptionHandler(DocumentNotFoundException.class)
public ResponseEntity<?> handleException(DocumentNotFoundException e) {

    return ResponseEntity
        .status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
        .body("{\"error\": \"Invoice not found\"}");
}
```

This bypasses message conversion and results in a HTTP 404 response code.

Comment: Yeah, it's something I tried and it works, but I want to avoid it, becouse: 
*I want to return error in cosistent way with others endpoint
*In this scenario I should create a custom exception handlers for all possible exceptions, for returning ex. 400, 401, 404, etc.

Comment: Maybe you should try [Problems for Spring Web MVC](https://github.com/zalando/problem-spring-web) which is a library that makes it easy to produce `application/problem+json` responses from a Spring application. However, if my answer fixes your specific problem, please upvote as answer.

Comment: Actually this one is even better solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40421119/spring-return-json-for-http-406-not-acceptable/41123438 as it allows you to specify your handling of the Error message in one place instead of repeating yourself in each @ExceptionHandler (also, your handles can remain generic and return strict error type)

Answer (score 0):

To combat the infamous 406 issue, this is the solution I went with before the **fix** was released today (Jan 20, 2020) in Spring Boot [2.2.4](https://spring.io/blog/2020/01/20/spring-boot-2-2-4-released).

I extended `ResponseEntity<>` and forced it to always use JSON content type. Then I return this new instantiation in the global exception handler under the purview of the `@Rest/ControllerAdvice` like so:

```
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;

import static org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE;

public class JsonResponseEntity<T> extends ResponseEntity<T>
{
    // You need an inner class or else you will run into super() issues
    private static class Helper
    {
        private static MultiValueMap<String, String> headerHelper( @Nullable MultiValueMap<String, String> headers )
        {
            if ( headers == null )
            {
                headers = new HttpHeaders();
            }

            // The following is a generic version of: getHeaders().setContentType( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON ); // NOSONAR
            headers.set( CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8.toString() );
            return headers;
        }
    }

    public JsonResponseEntity( HttpStatus status )
    {
        this(null, Helper.headerHelper( null ), status);
    }

    public JsonResponseEntity( T body, HttpStatus status )
    {
        this(body, Helper.headerHelper( null ), status);
    }

    public JsonResponseEntity( MultiValueMap<String, String> headers, HttpStatus status )
    {
        super( Helper.headerHelper( headers ), status );
    }

    public JsonResponseEntity( T body, MultiValueMap<String, String> headers, HttpStatus status )
    {
        super( body, Helper.headerHelper( headers ), status );
    }
}
```

Then in the expection handler you can return:

```
@ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleMyException(MyException e) {
    ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, e.getLocalizedMessage()); // ErrorResponse is just a POJO

    // You can do this:
    // return ResponseEntity.status( 404 ).contentType( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON ).body( errorResponse );

    // or this:
    return new JsonResponseEntity<>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

By forcing the content type to JSON at the `ResponseEntity` level, the 406 issue should dissapear.